# Visio Web Drawing linking to Word bookmark in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word, hyperlink, visio

Versions : Visio - 2010, Word - 2010, SharePoint 2010

I am working on a Visio diagram which will be used in Sharepoint. So I am using the Visio Web Diagram Format in Visio.

I have my different shapes connecting to bookmarks in large Word documents. When testing in Visio itself, the hyperlinks to the bookmark work correctly and take me to the page where the bookmark is defined.

When I upload the same diagram to Sharepoint and click on the same shape, it opens up the word document, but it doesn't take me to the bookmark, It opens the document on first page.

Am I missing something in this set-up? Do I need to take any extra steps for the bookmarks to work from Sharepoint?